# retrieve database password from php file using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a js file that creates a form to collect clients contact info. When the form is submitted it sends a url string to the database. However the string needs to include a token and password to login to the database. So i need to somehow hide the token and password in a php file and add it to the string when the client hits submit. so far ive been able to get the data from a php file using .get or .ajax, but the js file already uses an .ajax request and i'm not sure how to combine them together. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
function initPopup() {
        // open on load
        if (xanadu_settings['show_popup'] == 'open') {
          openXanadu();
        }
        // open on mouse out
        else {
          $('html > body').mouseleave(function() {
            if (!popup_visible) {
              openXanadu();
            }
          });
        }
      }

      // This gets the login string i need to add to the form subit string below
      var dataString = 'login';

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "login.php",
        data: {data : dataString}, 

        success: function(data) {
          returnedvalue = data;
          console.log(data);

        }

      });


      $("#xanadu_wrapper form").validate({

        rules: {
          name: "required",
          email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
          name: "Please specify your name",
          email: {
            required: "We need your email address to contact you",
            email: "Your email address must be valid"
          }
        },


        submitHandler: function(form, data) {
          var report_url = "http://myLinkToTheAPI";
          var submit_data = {
            // token: $(form).find('input.token').val(),
            // pass: $(form).find('input.pass').val(),
            campaignId: $(form).find('input.campaignId').val(),
            ipAddress: $(form).find('input#ipAddress').val(),
            source: $(form).find('input.source').val(),
            name: $(form).find('input.name').val(),
            email: $(form).find('input.email').val(),
            phone: $(form).find('input.phone').val(),

          }


          var form_submitted = false;
          var submit_data = $(form).serialize();


          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: report_url,
            data: submit_data,

            complete: function() {
              if ( ($(form).attr('action') != '') && (form_submitted == false) ) {
                $(form)[0].submit();
                form_submitted = true;
              }
              $(form).find('input, button').attr('disabled', '');
              //Thank you! We will contact you shortly.
              $(form).after('<p class="success-alert">' + xanadu_settings['success_message'] + '</p>');
              $(form).next('.success-alert').fadeIn();
              console.log(form);
              console.log(form_submitted);

              if (xanadu_settings['prevent_after_submission'] == 'true') {
                setBlockCookie();
              }
            }
          });


          setTimeout(function(){
            if ( ($(form).attr('action') != '') && (form_submitted == false) ) {
              $(form)[0].submit();
              form_submitted = true;
            }
          }, 500);

        }

      });
```

Comment: We're going to need to see some code in order to recommend any changes to your setup.

Comment: The browser should never know your database access details. DB access should be handled by the server.

Comment: Why does the browser need to know anything about a database…?! How is Javascript sending anything "to the database"…?!

Comment: "However the string needs to include a token and password to login to the database" <-- please don't. This is a really really bad idea even with your file method as others have mentioned. Please rethink your implementation.

Comment: I just added the code to the post - hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: I think my suggestion would be to submit the form data to your own server instead of directly to the API, and then make a cURL request from your server to the API and include the token and password _there_. That way they are never exposed client-side.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Just do your updates / inserts in the AJAX call?

When they hit submit, serializeArray() the form, pass your form data to the receiving page, and handle all database interaction on the server. You should never store database information on the client.

Comment: okay, so i have this part `var submit_data = $(form).serialize();` and that puts all the form data into a string that is sent to the database. but i thought the token and password needed to be included in this string for the database to accept it. Your saying i can send the string without the login info and add it later when it gets to the server?

Comment: I think there's some confusion resulting from the misuse of some words (perhaps a language barrier). @user3063712 feel free to correct if I'm wrong, but it seems that you have a form and you are trying to send the data from the form to _an external 3rd-party service_ via an API.  This API requires sending the data with a token and password. You are currently storing the token and password in your own db, and when the form page loads, you are making a request to fetch this info so that you can then inject them into the API request when the form is submitted.

Comment: Editing for Patrick's response:
If what Patrick is saying is correct, you'll need to make some alterations. Have the AJAX point to an independent php page. Grab the API info from your database there, build your API packet, and send the info to the API from there. You can then pass the API response to the client if you need.

Comment: patrick Q - you are right except i don't have the login stored in a db, i just have it stored in an external php file. the form has to go on a 3rd party site that only gives me access to a wysiwyg. so I can add the js script and a div to load the form in to.

Comment: @user3063712 So see my comment under your question for an idea what to do. I don't have time to code it all up for you, but it should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: that makes total sense! Thank you so much. I was pretty stuck, the guy who runs the api told me to make a cURL request too. I just haven't done that before.